# SxS (Side-by-Side) not working

Tags: delphi, dll, manifest

Following up from my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074563/registration-free-com-dll/5078671#5078671): I did all the steps provided by Steve, the SxS Parse log is empty, but I still get a "Class Not Registered" error.

I know my .exe is using my custom .manifest, because if I change the Version of my assembly to something incorrect, I get the "Side-by-side configuration" error, however when everything matches, I get the Class Not Registered error.

The .manifests I use are found in my last question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this and skip side by side manifests.  my findings are they don't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <ms_asmv2:trustInfo xmlns:ms_asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <ms_asmv2:security>
            <ms_asmv2:requestedPrivileges>
                <ms_asmv2:requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker">
                </ms_asmv2:requestedExecutionLevel>
            </ms_asmv2:requestedPrivileges>
        </ms_asmv2:security>
    </ms_asmv2:trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this question is very old, and so I cannot try this out, since I am no longer working on the project the question was meant for. :)