# Registration-free COM/DLL with multiple versions of the same typelib (SxS)

Tags: delphi, dll, com, activex, registration-free-com

In the question below, has a very nice instruction on how to make a Delphi use ActiveX controls in a registration free manner.

[Registration-free COM/DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074563/registration-free-com-dll/53429764#53429764)

But I have an additional question - can this also be used to support multiple versions of the same COM-object as independent objects? I think .NET can, but we need it in our Win32 application.

The reason is that we use a third party component, which has only one interface (GUID) but has different behavior (calculations) based on the version of the dll.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use multiple versions of a COM/SxS library in the same process by using a separate [Activation Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/activation-contexts) for each version.