# How to have multiple versions of a Delphi COM Server at the same time?

Tags: delphi, com, regfreecom

We have a COM server written in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo which contains 4 classes, all of which inherit from `TAutoObject`, and all have an `initialization` section containing the call to `TAutoObjectFactory.Create`.

In a typical installation, we have approximately 60 other programs that make use of the classes in the COM server. This all works fine. Each of the classes has their own *GUID* and the **Delphi COM server** does its usual thing of ensuring they are all registered correctly as part of the `InitComServer` process that runs from `Application.Initialize`.

We now have a need to run multiple installations side-by-side, where they may be different versions. Since we don't control all of the programs, we can't produce a different version of the COM server with different *GUID's* for every installation.

I had found this Microsoft document:

[DLL/COM Redirection on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/win32/sbscs/dll-com-redirection-on-windows)

But that approach does not work. When the main program starts and creates an instance of the first COM server class, I can see that it is the registered EXE that is running, not the COM server EXE in the same folder as the main program. This might be because it's an EXE and not a DLL, and **Delphi's** initialization is circumventing the DLL/COM redirection.

Here's an example of using one of the COM classes:

```
function ProduceReport(const ATenantID, AReportID: Integer; const AFilter: String): String;
var
  AReportServer: IReportServer;
begin
  Result := '';

  AReportServer := CoReportServer.Create;

  try
    if AReportServer.Connect(ATenantID) then
    begin
      if not AReportServer.Print(AReportID, AFilter) then
        Result := AReportServer.GetLastError;
    end
    else
      Result := AReportServer.GetLastError;

  except on E: Exception do
    Result := E.Message;
  end;

  AReportServer := nil;
end;
```

The main thing of note is that the `CoReportServer.Create` does this internally:

```
Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_ReportServer) as IReportServer;
```

which in turn is doing this:

```
OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(ClassID, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown, Result));
```

I can't see what `CoCreateInstance` is doing, but I am wondering if there is a way to call `CoGetInstanceFromFile` instead? Perhaps by changing the `CoReportServer.Create` in the TLB to use my own code instead of the `CreateComObject`?

Would changing the call to `TAutoObjectFactory.Create` to use a different `TClassInstancing`, such as `ciSingleInstance`, make any difference?

I just want it so that when a program calls `CoReportServer.Create`, it creates an instance of the server from the EXE it has in the program's folder, not by looking up the *InprocServer* from the Registry. I don't want the Registry to be used at all.

[Edit]

Since we also have an OCX that will need to be registry-free, I followed the steps discussed in this post:

[Generate manifest files for registration-free COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465882/generate-manifest-files-for-registration-free-com)

I have a manifest file for the OCX test app and a manifest file the OCX itself, both of which are in the same folder as the test app and the OCX. The manifest file specifies the same version number of the OCX as the one in the folder.

I then copied an old version of the OCX to a different folder, ran an elevated CMD prompt, and used *Regsvr32* to register that OCX in that folder.

Running the OCX test app, which includes the *ActiveX* control on the main form, I can see from *Process Explorer* that it is using the registered OCX, and not the OCX in the same folder.

This may indicate that **Delphi** EXE programs can't handle the manifest approach to this, even if I include the custom manifest in the **Project Options**.

We have a mix of COM server EXE, ActiveX visual control OCX, and ActiveX type library DLL, all written in **Delphi 10.2 Tokyo**, that we need to make registry-free.

[Edit 23/03/2022]

I've made some progress on this by referencing the information contained in the answer for [Registration-free COM/DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074563/registration-free-com-dll)

I now have a manifest file for the DLL containing an `<assemblyIdentity>` tag, a `<file>` tag containing a list of `<comClass>` tags for each CLSID in my DLL, and a list of `<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub>` tags to link the CLSID's and IID's with the interface name.

And there is a manifest file for the host EXE, that includes the same `<assemblyIdentity>` tag information, but contained within a `<dependentAssembly>` tag.

Using **SxSTrace**, I can see *"INFO: Activation Context generation succeeded."*, so at least the side-by-side configuration is correct.

However, when running the test program, at the point it is calling `CoReportServer.Create`, it is falling over with a *"Error loading type library/DLL"* message. Based on the stack trace, this is from the `LoadTypeLibrary` call inside the `TAutoObjectFactory.Create` process from the `initialization` section of the first class implementation of the first interface.

Since the SO answer I looked at mentions making sure it will work when the DLL is registered, I tried using **regsvr32** from an elevated command prompt, but get a *"Runtime error 217"* popup, followed by *"The module "reportserver.dll" failed to load. A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed."*

The Result from `LoadTypeLibEx` is *-2147312566*, which doesn't seem to match the `TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY` result.

So it looks like I may have got the registry-free COM part to work, but the conversion of the out-of-process COM server to an in-process COM library isn't right.

So I went back to the COM server EXE, and re-registered that to confirm the test program still works. It did. Then I altered the test program manifest to point to the COM server EXE instead of my trial conversion DLL, made a new manifest file for the COM server EXE, containing all the IID's and CLSID's, and un-registered the EXE.

The test program reports *"Class not registered"*, so that pretty much confirms the activation context approach only works on DLL's.

That leaves me with figuring out why the DLL will not load, although another issue I just thought of is that the DLL is in-process, meaning every program that uses the library has to create it's own instance. That could be very resource intensive.

[Edit 25/03/2022]

Skipping the out-of-process COM server for the moment, I've now taken a look at our ActiveX Control, which is a descendent of a `TProgressBar` and is used either on a *VCL form* or created at runtime.

Following the same approach for defining the manifest file, I've created the `<assemblyIdentify>`, `<file>` and `<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub>` tags, but I noticed that in the *_TLB.pas*, there is one extra `TGUID` for `DIID_IReportControlEvents`.

Reviewing the Microsoft documentation for manifest files, I cannot see any reference to an events type of interface, so I'm not sure how that one will work.

In any case, a manifest file doesn't work for an OCX. I just get the *"Class not registered"* error.

The **SxStrace** file shows *"INFO: Activation Context generation succeeded."* but it doesn't include any information about the manifest for the OCX, so it is not loading it at all.

This is probably because the *_TLB.pas* for the OCX shows it is using **OleControl** rather than **COM**. Removing the `{$E ocx}` from the DPR means **Delphi** creates a DLL instead, but that also fails.

Comment: What you are looking for is "Registration-free COM" or "Isolated COM", but it can be tricky (ie, near impossible) to use for a COM EXE server. Have a look at [this discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3849f22d-c8b8-429e-a03a-37601411acec/registrationfree-exe-com-server-) on MSDN.

Comment: @RemyLebeau. Thanks for the comment and the question edit. I believe you are right in that a Registry-less COM EXE is going to be very difficult, mainly because of all the core ActiveX COM code in Delphi. Something I'm considering is moving all the functionality into a regular DLL, making the necessary changes to our programs to work that way, and writing a COM wrapper around the DLL for third-party programs we can't change. Just means that they can't be included in our multi-tenant infrastructure until they've been changed to use LoadLibrary instead of CreateComObject.

Comment: @RemyLebeau. After reading that MSDN post, I did a little more Googling and found this: [Creating Registration-Free COM Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/creating-registration-free-com-objects)

Comment: I think you are on the right track to move your COM objects out of the EXE and into a DLL, which can then be manifested.  I haven't done regfree COM in Delphi but the manifest file approach is something supported directly by Windows, IIRC. When it finds a manifest that means the registry lookups should be circumvented entirely for manifested GUIDs.  I suppose you could use the activation context stuff directly, but normally I think that's not needed because basically the manifest file is just a higher-level route of doing that. Maybe if Delphi somehow conflicts with manfesting you'd need to.

Comment: When you create a new ActiveX Library project in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, the DPR automatically exports DllRgisterServer and DllunregisterServer methods. These allow registering/deregestering the DLL using RegSvr32. Removing these should stop any registry use, and then I can see what Manifest file settings I need for the host program to make use if the ActiveX library.